# Lua API for TokyoTyrant

Tags: lua

I didn't managed to find an Lua client/api for TokyoTyrant.
Such Api exists for TokyoCabinet, but not for TT. And Perl and Ruby API exists for TT.
TT provides a native binary  protocol, a memcached-compatible protocol, and an HTTP-oriented protocol.

So my questions are :

1/ Do you think using the memcached (using luamemcached) or the HTTP protocol (using luaSocket) is "enough" for most / simple usage, and so a native Lua api is not necessary ?
(the app is a simple uuid storage/distributor) ?

2/ Does it make sense to not use TokyoTyrant, but only TokyoCabinet, and use Lua at the application level to provide network and concurrent access to TC, using, say, Copas (Copas is , from their website, "a dispatcher based on coroutines that can be used by TCP/IP servers." ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Google pointed me to http://github.com/phoenixsol/lua-tokyotyrant.

Comment: Thanks for the link, i missed it.
Unfortunately, this driver does not implements the API of the table extension (tcrdbtblput, tcrdbtblputkeep, ...).
I guess perhaps i can use this driver as a template to implement the missing part.